# Visual studio 2017 - error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code 2

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Building a project with Visual Studio 2017 i came across this error:

> error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code 2.

here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    const int WIDTH=800;
    const int HEIGHT=600;

    Bitmap bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    unique_ptr<int[]> histogram(new int[Mandelbrot::MAX_ITERATIONS + 1]{ 0 });

    unique_ptr<int[]> fractal(new int[WIDTH*HEIGHT]{ 0 });
    //int fractal[WIDTH*HEIGHT]{ 0 };

    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            double xFractal = (x - WIDTH / 2 - 200)*2.0 / HEIGHT;
            double yFractal = (y - HEIGHT / 2)*2.0 / HEIGHT;

            int iterations = Mandelbrot::getIterations(xFractal, yFractal);
            if (iterations != Mandelbrot::MAX_ITERATIONS) {
                histogram[iterations]++;
            }
            fractal[y*WIDTH + x] = iterations;
            uint8_t color = 256 * (double)iterations / Mandelbrot::MAX_ITERATIONS;
            color = color*color*color;
            bitmap.setPixels(x, y, color, color, color);
        }
    }

    bitmap.write("Mandelbrot.bmp");
    return 0;
}
```

the problem seems to be the declaration of the fractal array:

```
unique_ptr<int[]> fractal(new int[WIDTH*HEIGHT]{ 0 });
```

if i comment that (and the other lines with the fractal variable) the code compiles just fine, and if i change the unique pointer into a normal int array the code compiles but it throws an exception when i debug it, signaling a stack overflow.

Reducing the size of the array solves the problem, so it looks like the program doesn't have enough memory space to run. I googled quite a lot and found that visual studio limits the stack size to 1MB by deafult (i might be wrong on that), but i can't find how to increase it manually in visual studio 2017. Can someone help me?

EDIT: here is the complete output:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: Fractal, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>
> 1>Main.cpp 1>INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>
> Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX86\x86\CL.exe'
>
> 1>    Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ 1>
>
> Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more
>
> information 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>
> Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(360,5):
>
> error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code 2. 1>Done building project
>
> "Fractal.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Off-topic: I'm confused why you are using `unique_ptr<int[]>` instead of `std::vector<int>` (or `std::array` as your sizes can be compile time constants)

Comment: The line of the error you show us is the least informative. Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error message into the question body.

Comment: Edited with the complete error message. I'm still a beginner and i'm following a course, honestly i used unique pointers because they were used on the course. I just now tried with the vector and it works, while the array throws this exception: "Unhandled exception at 0x01393089 in Fractal.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00482000). occurred". I'm confused now, why would the vector work?

Comment: Because stack space is limited. By default it's 1MB. A vector allocates the underlying array on the heap.

Answer (score 5):

`new int[N] { 0 }` does not mean "*fill the array with zeroes*", it actually means *aggregate-initialize the array by setting the first element to 0, and value-initialize the rest* (which sets the rest to 0). For example if you wrote `{ 1 }`, that would set the first element to `1` but the rest would still be `0`.

Since you're already relying on value-initialization, you might as well remove the `0` from `{0}`, that incidentally also makes your code compile:

```
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> fractal(new int[WIDTH*HEIGHT] {});
```

---

As to why your original code doesn't compile - it's clearly a bug in Visual Studio 2017. Feel free to [report it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017?view=vs-2017).

Here's a minimal application to reproduce the issue:

```
int main()
{
  auto test = new int[200000]{1};
  delete[] test;
}
```